# Can inner CSS model be edited like SVG with JavaScript or it's non-editable?

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to rewrite my app for SVG processing, and ATM should know whether I should keep untouched CSS model in memory (because there's a possibility of updates to it) and fetch styles when SVG elements get called or, if it's non-editable, unpack it right into SVG.

While from my previous experience it seems more reasonable to keep untouched CSS & not unpack it from the get-go (don't do what you haven't been told to do), it may be harder to make such a design.

Answer (score 0):

At [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Style-20001113/css.html) it is said that:

> All CSS objects in the DOM are "live", that is, a change in the style sheet is reflected in the computed and actual style.

This statement only implies that CSS can be edited, but from the IDL in [section 2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Style-20001113/css.html#CSS-fundamental-h2) it becomes obvious that while values in rules cannot be changed, the rules themselves can be added or deleted. Hence, taking into account the nature of CSS, i.e. the ability to override rules, inner CSS model (the one that represent CSS file in RAM) can be edited.